# Drag UIView along bezier path

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I need to drag UIView along bezier path from one point to another, What is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to do drag a uiview from one point to another point.

```
UIBezierPath *path  = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:startingPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:endPoint]; //you can use addCurveToPoint: , addArcToPoint:, etc

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
pathAnimation.path = path;
pathAnimation.removeOnCompletion = NO ;
[myView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
```

Comment: This is not moving `UIView`, but `CALayer` instead.